# Hide category with no data after hiding series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked bar chart that with multiple series and categories.
When showing/hiding the series, I want the categories having no data to hide.
This works fine when it is the first or last category, but the middle category doesn't disappear.

In the following snippet, when hiding the `A` series (by clicking in the legend) the category `1` disappears. But when I hide, `B` and `C`, the `2` category doesn't disappear. What I want is that the middle categories to disappear too (no more white space in the middle).

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },      
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'A',
            data: [{ x: 0, y: 5 }]
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            data:  [{ x: 1, y: 4 }]
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            data:  [{ x: 1, y: 4 }]
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            data: [{ x: 2, y: 2 }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 800px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I already tried:

- passing the data as an array,
- not specifying the category array, because I don't really want to show the category, but I don't want the space to be kept when there is no data
- play around with stacking

I know this could be achieved programmatically, that's no problem. But, what I would like to know is:

- is this a bug/feature?
- is there a Highcharts option that I missed?
- do you have any different suggestions of how can I achieve something similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd call it a bug, because it's an inconsistency in how categories are treated depending on their order. It's not a linear scale, those are independent categories, so it shouldn't matter which is on the "edge" and which is in the middle. Other than programmatically modifying chart, I see no way around this.

Comment: @jkondratowicz thanks for your reply, I submitted an issue and I will see how it turns out.

Comment: 1) No, there is no option you've missed 2) though the behavior may be up for debate, it is not a bug. When you hide data at the start or end of the axis, you have changed the axis extremes, and the axis responds accordingly. When you hide data in the middle, the axis extremes are unaffected and therefore there is no corresponding response from the axis. To change this, you will have to capture the legend item click event, and build a function to rebuild the axis categories according to the visible data.